# Processed live video via Ethernet transfer

Tags: python, camera, ethernet, streaming-video, opencv

I'm trying to track an object with a webcam and my pi (let's call it pi1). Therefore I have a python script, which gives me a processed live video as an output. Besides, I have another pi (pi2) which is connected to pi1 via Ethernet cable. My question is how do I transfer the processed live video from pi1 to pi2 via Ethernet ?

Answer (score 1):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956830/what-kind-of-stream-gstreamer-produce) has a gstreamer example that should work with some minor tweaking:

> Sending side:
>
> ```
> raspivid -t 999999 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=$RA-IP-ADDR port=5000
> ```
>
> Receiving side:
>
> ```
> gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=$RA-IP-ADDR port=5000  ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
> ```